# Javascript: Assign percentage of players a random role

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, percentage, weighted-average

Let's say I have these two arrays

```
let players = ["ryan", "austin", "julian", "kelso", "mitch", "adam", "dwight", "edwin", "connor", "george"]
let roles = []
```

I would like to populate **roles** with, let's say 30% of 'Good' and 70% 'Bad' strings in a random order, but always 30% of 'Good' roles.

```
example: roles: ['Bad','Bad','Bad','Bad','Good','Bad','Bad','Bad','Good','Good']
```

I am currently running this scenario which randomly creates an array, but without the percent requirements of 'Good' vs 'Bad'.

```
players: [ ]
roles: []

while (good === false || bad === false) {
    roles = []
    for (i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
        let randomise = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)
        if (randomise === 0) {
            roles.push("Good")
            innocent = true
        } else {
            roles.push("Bad")
            traitor = true
        }
    };
}
```

Can't wrap my head around how I could achieve my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identify how many players must be good by multiplying by `3 / 10` `ceil`'d. In the loop, push a random good or bad value to the array. But, also check if you've reached the limit of good or bad values to push, in which case push the other value

```js
const players = ["ryan", "austin", "julian", "kelso", "mitch", "adam", "dwight", "edwin", "connor", "george"]
let goodCount = Math.ceil(players.length * 3 / 10);
console.log('Need total of', goodCount, 'good');
const roles = []
for (let i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
  if (goodCount === 0) {
    // Rest of the array needs to be filled with bad:
    roles.push('Bad'); continue;
  }
  if (goodCount === players.length - roles.length) {
    // Rest of the array needs to be filled with good:
    roles.push('Good'); goodCount--; continue;
  }
  if (Math.random() < 0.3) {
    roles.push('Good'); goodCount--;
  } else {
    roles.push('Bad');
  }
};
console.log(roles);
```

Remember to [use `const`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278652/how-much-should-i-be-using-let-vs-const-in-es6) instead of `let` when possible, and remember to always declare your variables before using them (such as the `i` in the `for` loop), else you'll implicitly create global variables, and throw errors in strict mode.

Comment: This doesn't consistently result in 30% of Good roles.

Comment: You said you wanted the roles to be random. Randomness is not guaranteed to result in the average ratio.

Comment: I guess I should have better clarified. I need 30% to always be Good, but in a random order.  I will modify my question to include that.

Comment: Ok, see edit, figure out how many Goods you need first, then subtract on each iteration

Comment: This is beautiful.  Thank you for leaving comments as well so It's easier to understand and learn from!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just generate an array of 70% "bad" and 30% "good", then shuffle that array:

```
const players = ["ryan", "austin", "julian", "kelso", "mitch", "adam", "dwight",  "edwin", "connor", "george"];
const roles = [];

const badNum = Math.floor(0.7 * players.length);
const goodNum = players.length - badNum;

for (let i = 1; i <= players.length; i++) {
    roles.push(i <= badNum ? "bad" : "good");
}

//Shuffle roles
for (let i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (roles.length - i)) + i;
    var selection = roles[randomIndex];
    var extract = roles[i];
    roles[i] = selection;
    roles[randomIndex] = extract;
}
```